# Merging data from two dataframes for training

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following two dataframe :

```
data = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/digit-recognition/train_data.csv')
data_custom = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/digit-recognition/custom-data.csv',header=None)
```

I want to train my KNN model on the combined data. Is there a way to combine these two dataframes. The normal merge may not work
directly as the column headers are present in one and not the other. Althought there structure is exam same.
**custom-data.csv** file 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Qj-zfWoaYbMMbEin1K0dFbFHfDFr_t85/view?usp=sharing
**train_data.csv** file 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yDmKBt-boMfaF5LK2SN7MM8LeUZ1p6vD/view?usp=sharing
final_data = pd.concat([data, data_custom]) produces the following output

[image]

Here is the screenshot of custom-data.csv file 
[image]

And here is the screenshot of train_data.csv file top rows -

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try `pd.concat`:

```
data.columns = data_custom.columns
final_data = pd.concat([data, data_custom])
```

Comment: Did you try concat yourself for the dataset he shared?

Comment: @U12-Forward it converted everything in data to NaN. I am posting the screenshot of final_data in the OP

Comment: @sunny Can you please post a screenshot of the `data_custom` file?

Comment: @U12-Forward posted the screenshot. Its the same files that I shared with a google drive link

Comment: @sunny Please check it out now, i edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

You could definitely use [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) as said by @U12-Forward

Otherwise you should take a look at [this page](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html) where it shows the difference between concat, merge, join and append, depending on what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("train_data.csv")
data_custom = pd.read_csv('custom-data.csv', header=None)

# combining data_custom df as row to the end of data df:
entry = data_custom.iloc[0].values
data.loc[len(data)] = entry
```

data shape at start: (42000, 785)

data shape after combining: (42001, 785)

The custom data is combined as another row.